# Producto punto entre dos vectores

Tags: c

Sólo se puede hacer con *vectores* ( o *formaciones* o *arreglos* )  de la misma dimensión. ¿ Está bien ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){
  int a[20],b[20],c[20];
  int i,j,na,nb,suma;

  //Lectura de A
  printf("Tamaño del vector A: ");
  scanf("%d",&na);
  printf("Tamaño del vector B: ");
  scanf("%d",&nb);

  //Lectura de elementos de A
  for(i=0;i<na;i++)
  {
    printf("a(%d) = ", i+1);
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);      
  }

  //Lectura de elementos de B
  for(i=0;i<nb;i++)
  {
     printf("b(%d) = ", i+1);
     scanf("%d",&b[i]);         
  }

  //Producto de los vestores    
  suma=0;
  for(i=0;i<na;i++) 
  {
    suma+=a[i]*b[i];    
  }
  c[i]=suma;

  printf("EL resultado es:%d",c[i]);
}
```

Comment: Pues la verdad es que ni idea: ¿ Que resultados esperas ? ¿ Que resultados obtienes ? Como no coloques un ejemplo de valores y resultados ... pues va a ser difícil ayudarte.

Comment: Debes ser más preciso. Hay producto interno de vectores (producto escalar o punto) y producto vectorial. Por la sumatoria en la última parte de tu código se trata de un producto interno. Pero, no veo para qué usar el array c, es innecesario.

Comment: El producto escalar (punto) debe ser entre vectores con el mismo tamaño, si no no estará definido.